# No Activity found Exception

Tags: android

I have downloaded the sample code from this site for FTP Client http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/index.html

But when I ran the project I got this exception and crashed.

```
03-27 21:40:44.572: INFO/System.out(559): EEE  : No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=ftp://192.168.20.128 typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri (has extras) }
```

What is the reason for this?
Can anyone provide me a fully working android code for FTP.

This is the code for downloading.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                // FTP URL (Starts with ftp://, sftp://, ftps:// or scp:// followed by hostname and port).
                Uri ftpUri = Uri.parse("ftp://192.168.20.128");
                intent.setDataAndType(ftpUri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri");
                // Download
                intent.putExtra("command_type", "download");
                // FTP credentials (optional)
                intent.putExtra("ftp_username", "anonymous");
                intent.putExtra("ftp_password", "test@test.com");
                //intent.putExtra("ftp_keyfile", "/sdcard/dsakey.txt");
                //intent.putExtra("ftp_keypass", "optionalkeypassword");
                // FTP settings (optional)
                intent.putExtra("ftp_pasv", "true");
                //intent.putExtra("ftp_resume", "true");
                //intent.putExtra("ftp_encoding", "UTF-8");
                //intent.putExtra("ftps_mode", "implicit");
                // Activity title
                intent.putExtra("progress_title", "Downloading files ...");
                // Remote files to download.
                intent.putExtra("remote_file1", "/remotefolder/subfolder/file1.zip");
                intent.putExtra("remote_file2", "/remotefolder/subfolder/file2.zip");
                // Target local folder where files will be downloaded.
                intent.putExtra("local_folder", "/sdcard/localfolder"); 
                intent.putExtra("close_ui", "true");    
                startActivityForResult(intent, DOWNLOAD_FILES_REQUEST);
```

I get error at "startActivityForResult"

Comment: No, what is the need for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, you need to install AndFTP in order to be able to work with FTP (unless you implement the FTP functionality by your self).

Let me guess what you did: you thought that by implementing the snippets of code that you found in the andFtp website you were going to be able to use FTP in your application.

If I guessed right, then you do not understand completely how Android works and what you have to do in order to use FTP. So, what andFTP does is register offer some activities that can be used by external apps in order to use FTP. However, in order for it to work the andFTP application **must be installed**.

That's why you get an `ActivityNotFound` exception. So here are your only two choices:

- Either you implement all the FTP stuff by your self (and forget about andFTP)
- Or you catch that kind of exceptions and show a message to the user telling them that they have to install andFTP so that your app can operate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that activity is listed in the android manifest? It would cause that kind of error.

Comment: yes i have only one activity and it is listed in the Manifest.

Comment: did you added this intent filter to you mainactivity?

   <intent-filter>

   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri" />
   
</intent-filter>

Comment: Yes, I added it but still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have  to define your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.
If you are using any activity which is working in your android application you have to define in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I have only one activity and I have declared it in the manifest file.